# Install passenger with yum-installed nginx

Tags: centos, nginx, yum, phusion-passenger

Is it possible to install passenger into nginx that has been installed previously using yum?

I need to provide a directory prefix for the install-nginx-module, just wondering where that would be on Centos?

```
passenger-install-nginx-module  --auto-download --auto --prefix=$nginx_directory_prefix
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the Passenger developers provides a [yum repository for RHEL/CentOS](http://passenger.stealthymonkeys.com/). (You need EPEL to use it.) This is probably the easiest way to get up and running.

Comment: Looks like the yum packages are a fiar bit behind ... seems like building from source might be the safest option?

Comment: That depends entirely on your environment and business requirements.

Answer (score 1):

No. Nginx does not support loadable modules. It is impossible to install Phusion Passenger into an existing Nginx binary without recompilation.